# When post request is done in postman it passes all the values as NULL

Tags: java, postman

> This is my back end where the method is taking a student object and a String Id.

```
@PostMapping(path="/edit/student")
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void editStudent(@RequestBody Student student,String id){
    ss.editStudent(student,id);
}
```

> When I try to do a post request using postman it sends null for everything.

```
{
"student":{
    "firstname": "jay",
    "lastname": "patel",
    "studentId": "2",
    "email": "temp163@gmail.com"
},
"id":"1"}
```

> Check this out. this may help a little to understand.
>   [Backend gets everything as null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz3nJ.png)
>
> This is the post-call from the postman.
>   [Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQFvK.png)

Comment: Add more details... refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Best practice is to post the minimum code necessary to replicate the issue in your question. No one wants to transcribe your code from the image in order to replicate your problem or test it.

Comment: Don't post text as png. That's just rude...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the JSON that you're sending as your POST payload is **not** a representation of a Student object.  Instead, it's a representation of an object that contains two members, a Student object named `student`, and a String named `id`.

```
{
  "student":{ //<-- This is a Student object
    "firstname": "jay",
    "lastname": "patel",
    "studentId": "2",
    "email": "temp163@gmail.com"
  },
  "id":"1" //<-- This is a String
}
```

If that payload were deserialized into a Java class, it would look like this:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public Student student;
    public String id;
}
```

In short, your REST endpoint is expecting a Student object, but that's not what you're providing it with, and it can't deserialize this "SomeObject" representation into an instance of Student.

Try changing your payload to be the representation of just the Student object that the endpoint is expecting:

```
{
  "firstname": "jay",
  "lastname": "patel",
  "studentId": "2",
  "email": "temp163@gmail.com"
}
```